# Salvando imagens PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um pequeno código que pega a imagem, da um nome `random` para ela e salva em uma pasta. Mas agora preciso que nesse mesmo código gere a mesma imagem mas com o tamanho `100x100` e salve na mesma pasta com mesmo nome, só que acrescentando no final "`_small`". Como posso fazer isto?

```
   <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$file = file_get_contents("php://input");
$id = $_GET['photoId'];

if(strlen($file) < 50) {
    die("2");
}

$imageName = substr(md5(time() . rand(1, 9999)), 0, 24);
file_put_contents("../photo/" . $imageName . ".png", $file);

echo $imageName;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma função pra redimensionar a imagem, utilizando ImageMagick ou GD. Depois faça uma cópia do arquivo e redimensione.

```php
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$file = file_get_contents("php://input");
$id = $_GET['photoId'];

if(strlen($file) < 50) {
    die("2");
}

$imageName = substr(md5(time() . rand(1, 9999)), 0, 24);

function resize_image($file, $w, $h) {
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
   $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
   $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
   imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
   return $dst;
}


file_put_contents("../photo/" . $imageName . ".png", $file);

$photo = "../photo/" . $imageName . ".png";
$photosmall = "../photo/" . $imageName . "_small" . ".png";

if (!copy($photo, $photosmall)) {
    echo "falhou ao copiar $photo...\n";
}

$imgsmall = resize_image($photosmall, 100, 100);

echo $imageName;

?>
```